# color (solid) individual nodes in tikzpicture matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, nodes, matrices

in the following MWE, I create a 'Coates diagram' I use for one of my classes. What I haven't been able to figure out is...how to colour the individual nodes? I want them to be solid, say, RGB-based incrementing greyscale for nodes 1 -> 3. This should be easy, but I haven't stumbled across the right 'search phrase'.

Pointers to the obvious solution?  Thanks in advance...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations,shapes,arrows,matrix,positioning}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

Here is a figure:

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\rule[-1.75cm]{0pt}{3.95cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=1.5pt,transform canvas={scale=1.05}]
\matrix (a) [matrix of nodes,row sep=0.5em, column sep=5em,every node/.style={circle,draw,font=\sffamily,minimum width=1cm,thick}]
{ A & B & C \\};
\path[>=stealth,font=\small,thick] (a-1-1) edge node[below] {{\footnotesize $S^A\psi^{AB}$}} (a-1-2);
\path[>=stealth,font=\small,thick] (a-1-2) edge node[below] {{\footnotesize $S^B\psi^{BC}$}} (a-1-3);
\path[>=stealth,->,font=\small,thick] (a-1-3) edge [bend right=50] node [above] {$S_C\psi^{CA}$} (a-1-1) ;
\path[>=stealth,->,font=\small,thick] (a-1-1) edge [loop, below, out=240, in=300, looseness=10, distance=0.9cm] node  {{\footnotesize $S^A\bigl(1-\psi^{AB}\bigr)$}} (a-1-1) ;
\path[>=stealth,->,font=\small,thick] (a-1-2) edge [loop, below, out=240, in=300, looseness=10, distance=0.9cm] node  {{\footnotesize $S^B\bigl(1-\psi^{BC}\bigr)$}} (a-1-2) ;
\path[>=stealth,->,font=\small,thick] (a-1-3) edge [loop, below, out=240, in=300, looseness=10, distance=0.9cm] node  {{\footnotesize $S^C\bigl(1-\psi^{CA}\bigr)$}} (a-1-3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could consider going through all your previous questions and accept the most helpful answer (if it solved your problem, of course). That will mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways of achieving this I think. One way is to add specific styles for each cell, which you can do by adding `|[<list of options>]|` at the start of the cell, e.g. `|[fill=black!50]|`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations,shapes,arrows,matrix,positioning}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

Here is a figure:

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\rule[-1.75cm]{0pt}{3.95cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=1.5pt,transform canvas={scale=1.05}]
\matrix (a) [matrix of nodes,row sep=0.5em, column sep=5em,every node/.style={circle,draw,font=\sffamily,minimum width=1cm,thick}]
{ |[fill=black!20]|A & |[fill=black!50]|B & |[fill=black!80]| C \\};
\path[>=stealth,font=\small,thick] (a-1-1) edge node[below] {{\footnotesize $S^A\psi^{AB}$}} (a-1-2);
\path[>=stealth,font=\small,thick] (a-1-2) edge node[below] {{\footnotesize $S^B\psi^{BC}$}} (a-1-3);
\path[>=stealth,->,font=\small,thick] (a-1-3) edge [bend right=50] node [above] {$S_C\psi^{CA}$} (a-1-1) ;
\path[>=stealth,->,font=\small,thick] (a-1-1) edge [loop, below, out=240, in=300, looseness=10, distance=0.9cm] node  {{\footnotesize $S^A\bigl(1-\psi^{AB}\bigr)$}} (a-1-1) ;
\path[>=stealth,->,font=\small,thick] (a-1-2) edge [loop, below, out=240, in=300, looseness=10, distance=0.9cm] node  {{\footnotesize $S^B\bigl(1-\psi^{BC}\bigr)$}} (a-1-2) ;
\path[>=stealth,->,font=\small,thick] (a-1-3) edge [loop, below, out=240, in=300, looseness=10, distance=0.9cm] node  {{\footnotesize $S^C\bigl(1-\psi^{CA}\bigr)$}} (a-1-3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]